# How to check that the number is even?

Tags: python

How can I check with Python that the number is even?

Example:

- 22 | even
- 23 | not even

Comment: `number % 2 == 0` is what you want.

Comment: Yes i did, but i didn't find anything useful.

Comment: [nothing useful?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python+is+number+even)

Comment: Since the answer was very simple, I suggest you work a little harder on the Python basic stuff. You have to start somewhere, try to do it right ;)

Comment: Would the question upvoter care to explain?

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd imagine they wanted to balance the downvotes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem

Comment: @JamieTaylor, the second link in my results had the exact solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is your number:

```
if (x % 2) == 0:
    # x is even
else:
    # x is odd
```

Answer (score 3):

Where `x` is your number:

```
if (x % 2) == 0:
    print('is even')
else:
    print('is odd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Where x is your number

```
if x % 2 == 0:
  print '%s|even' % x
else:
  print '%s|odd' % x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isEven(x):
    return x%2==0
```

the modulus operator, represented the `%` key, calculates the remainder between x and 2. The definition of an even number is if it is divisable by 2, so `if x%2==0` is true, it is an even number so we return the boolean value `True`. Otherwise, if `x%2!=0`, that means that the number has a remainder after being divided by 2 which means it is not an even number so we return `False`